# Crucible of Worlds and Burgeoning

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Crucible of Worlds](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCrucible%20of%20Worlds%5d) says:

> You may play land cards from your graveyard.

[Burgeoning](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBurgeoning%5d) says:

> Whenever an opponent plays a land, you may put a land card from your hand onto the battlefield.

So, if I have both on the battlefield, whenever one of my opponents plays a land, may a put a land from my graveyard onto the battlefield?

My guess is not, based on the wording of the cards.  Because Burgeoning is not allowing me to "play a land" it is having me "put a land onto the battlefield" which is a different action.

Is this interpretation correct?  (I'd rather it be the other way...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You guessed right!  (Sorry.)  There are (at least) two reasons this combo doesn't work.

First: "Playing a land" is different than "putting a land card from your hand onto the battlefield."  They're not interchangeable.<sup>305.4</sup>  This means that the choice you can make for Burgeoning's effect is not changed by Crucible of Worlds.

Second: Crucible of Worlds doesn't affect the separation between the hand and the graveyard.  It simply allows you to take the "play a land" action with cards from an additional zone.  Since Burgeoning uses the phrase "a land card **from your hand**," the land that you choose cannot be in the graveyard.

---

> **305.4** Effects may also allow players to “put” lands onto the battlefield. This isn’t the same as “playing a land” and doesn’t count as a land played during the current turn.

Answer (score 1):

Well, because Crucible of the Worlds says "from your graveyard", you could only use this ability if you discarded lands somehow. Burgeoning means you can put a land from your HAND onto the battlefield if your opponent plays a land, so it wouldn't count as a land per turn.